# Obtaining object contour inside bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNggy.jpg)

I would like to detect the outline contour of the meat. I have trained a object detection model for meats. The output of the model can be seen below and the bounding box coordinates are (44,34) for top left and (321,348) for bottom right corners.

[Detected meat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZjyy.jpg)

How can i segmentate the meat's contour based on this output via opencv or other image processing libraries?

Comment: Do you think the depth estimate is correct? The surface below the beef seems perpendicular to the camera and flat, but this is not represented in the depth estimation.

Comment: [See here.](https://github.com/intel-isl/MiDaS/issues/38)

It is not 100% correct but I tested a book with normal contour detection on a flat surface, averaged the depth values inside the book's contour and the flat surface(reference), then linearly calculated the book's depth, then its thickness. This resulted in a 5% error.

Comment: Ok, do you only want to extract the contour of the beef? I think this can be achieved without depth estimation.

Comment: Yes! I also trained a model to detect meats(bounding box, not segmentation) if that helps.

Comment: You can easily obtain the segmentation from a bounding-box if the beef is always evident as in the picture. Could you update the question to make it clear that you want is a contour and have a bounding-box available? I will happily answer it.

Comment: I've made progress by using Otsu's thresholding to remove artifacts but it still wasn't enough. Updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Grabcut [1] algorithm to extract a segment from a bounding-box.

Grabcut tries to cluster the pixels into two groups, outside of the bounding-box and inside, while penalizing label disagreement with adjacent pixels with a similar color.

For example:

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('beef.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(im.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgd_model = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgd_model = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

rect = (30, 25, 30 + 318, 25 + 350)  # (x, y, w, h)
cv2.grabCut(im, mask, rect, bgd_model, fgd_model, 10, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)                      

mask = np.where((mask == cv2.GC_BGD) | (mask == cv2.GC_PR_BGD), 0, 1).astype(np.uint8)

contour, _= cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0)) 

cv2.imwrite("output.png", im)
```

[image: output.png]

[1] Rother, Carsten, Vladimir Kolmogorov, and Andrew Blake. " GrabCut" interactive foreground extraction using iterated graph cuts." ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG) 23.3 (2004): 309-314.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you face is due to the shadow in the top part, which makes the meat as dark as the background at places.

You can try to binarize the red component of the image, then remove the holes with a morphological closing, though this damages the outline a little.

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty awesome. What shape would you suggest for closing kernel?

Comment: I used an octagon, which is a simple approximation of a circle.

Comment: I'm getting similiar results but not as nice as yours. Could you also tell me what size and how many iterations you used for morph. closing if you still remember?

Comment: @aizuon: sorry, I don't remember. I increased until the "hole" disappered.